# Is it possible to store Functional/Acceptance config URL of Codeception outside repository?

Tags: php, git, functional-testing, codeception

I have a PHP project with Codeception on which several developers are working. Everyone have their own environment and different URL to their copy of the project. But in Codeception Functional/Acceptance yml config file we have to set up URL for acceptance and functional tests.

How could we have different URL to project and have main part of configs in repository? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @karma_police. I didn't understood at all! Sorry if I understood wrong, you want to use your repository configs in a local project? Or local configs with remote projects?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to look at the `$_SERVER['HOSTNAME']` value and select the appropriate url from that. I've currently got this in my `tests/acceptance/_bootstrap.php`

```
switch($_SERVER['HOSTNAME'])
{
  case 'dev1':
    $base_url = 'http://www.example.com.dev1';
    break;
  default:
    $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';
    break;
}
define("BASE_URL",$base_url);
```

You can then make use of this constant in a test

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('ensure that the a user can log in');
$I->amOnUrl(BASE_URL . "/home");
```

Comment: Thank you, it's possible way but we always have to redefine `BASE _URL` in each test. I still hope that there are a better solition through codeception environments files [docs](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments)

Comment: @karma_police, by putting the definition of `BASE_URL` in the bootstrap file, you only need to define it once and then it's available in each of your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I asked same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177532/codeception-configure-suite-test-path/32200652#32200652). I used `--environment` option to get this working.

here is the example configuration:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # add framework module here
        - Yii1
        - \Helper\Functional
        - PhpBrowser
        - Db
    config:
        Yii1:
            appPath: '/Volumes/disk0s4/www/new-proj/trunk/test.php'
            url: 'https://my.proj.local/test.php'
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'https://my.proj.didin/'
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test-proj-new'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'root'
env:
    my_env:
       modules:
            enabled:
                - Yii1
                - \Helper\Functional
            config:
                Yii1:
                     appPath: 'path to index.php of my environment'
                     url: 'http://my.local/test.php'
    production_env:
       modules:
            enabled:
                - Yii1
                - \Helper\Functional
            config:
                Yii1:
                     appPath: 'path to index.php of production environment'
                     url: 'http://my.local.com/test.php'
```

I know that config contains duplicated-lines and  should be able to be simplified, I've tried to simplify by removing duplicate line at global `modules`, but seems doesn't work to me.

So I let the config as you see above and I have created [Issue](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2302) for it, but still wondering if someone get this `overriding` working.

I hope this helps to anyone.