# Codeception, how override url from command line for a specific (or not specific) suite test?

Tags: codeception

I'm looking for a way to override the base url of my tests from the command line. In the future, I'll tests a lot of websites, so it's very unwieldy if I must add each website in a new environment in the `acceptance.suite.yml` file.

Currently, my `acceptance.suite.yml` is:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://foo.com
            browser: chrome
```

I see I can use the option 'override' with the run command, but even if I read the codeception document and navigate through help website (like stack overflox..), I can't find a good way for override. Can someone help me?

When I prints all config (via `./vendor/bin/concept`), I get:

```
Array
(
    actor => AcceptanceTester
    modules => Array
        (
            enabled => Array
                (
                    0 => Array
                        (
                            WebDriver => Array
                                (
                                    url => http://foo.foo
                                    browser => chrome
                                )
                        )
                    1 => \Helper\Acceptance
                )
            config => Array
                (
                )
            depends => Array
                (
                )
        )
```

I tried : `./vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --steps -o 'modules: enabled: 0: WebDriver: url: http://faa.faa`, but the test run ever on `http://foo.foo`

In this [codeception issue post](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3740#issuecomment-261682231), it seems it's impossible to override a config value when we run a specific suite (my english is not very good , so maybe I misunderstood). So I add an env in my `acceptance.suite.yml` file :

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://foo.foo
            browser: chrome
env:
    generic:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    url: http://faa.faa
```

And I tried theses commands :

`./vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --env generic --steps -o 'env: generic: modules: config: WebDriver: url: http://faa.faa`

And

`./vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --env generic --steps -o 'WebDriver: url: http://faa.faa`

And nothing happened. My test are always on `http://foo.foo`

**EDIT AFTER "LEGION" HELP**

When I use this `acceptance.suite.yml` :

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
      - WebDriver
  config:
    WebDriver:
      url: ''
      browser: ''

env:
  chrome:
    modules:
      config:
        WebDriver: {}
```

I get an error :

[image]

So when I use this `acceptance.suite.yml` :

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
  config:
    WebDriver:
      url: ''
      browser: chrome

env:
  chrome:
    modules:
      config:
        WebDriver: {}
```

I get an another error :

[image]

And if I use this `acceptance.suite.yml` :

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
  config:
    WebDriver:
      url: ''
      browser: chrome

env:
  chrome:
    modules:
      config:
        WebDriver:
          url: 'http://foo.foo'
          browser: 'chrome'
```

No error ! buuuUUUT ! I'm not on the good url x)

[image]

The url I get is "data:", its strange...
For get the url, I add this simple line in my test file :

```
$this->comment("I am on the url : " . $this->executeJS("return window.location.href") . "\n");
```

Comment: why downvote ? :/

Comment: I know is not exactly what you ask, but maybe that link can be helpful to reach your goal --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874410/is-it-possible-to-store-functional-acceptance-config-url-of-codeception-outside

Answer (score 0):

**N.B: You need Codeception 1.8 or above! Before that version is bugged.**

If the version is > 1.8 it should works... you may try editing your acceptance file like below and see if something is changed:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://foo.foo/'
            browser: 'firefox'

env:
    chrome: #or watherver you want
         modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    url: 'http://fuu.fuu/'
                    browser: 'chrome'
```

run it like below:

```
php vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --env chrome
```

** **EDIT** **

To pass the url from commandline you need empty WebDriver Configuration:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - WebDriver
        config:
            WebDriver: {}
env:
    chrome: #or watherver you want
         modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    url:'http://foo.foo'
                    browser:'firefox'
```

commandline:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --env chrome --steps -o 'WebDriver: url: \'http://faa.faa\' browser: \'chrome\''
```

(I usually use apex for url and browser... but not sure are really neded).

Comment: Thank you for your help :) this is work yes, but i'm looking for a solution without add each futur website in the "acceptance.suite.yml". I want be able to set the url from the command line as I said in the beginning of my post

Comment: Whops my bad, btw I think you can reach the goal with a little edit of my answer, just a sec.

Comment: I tested your edit, I have an error when I execute your command (WebDriver module is not configured! Options: browser, url are required). So, I added a default url and browser in the block "modules: enabled: -WebDriver: ..." from the "acceptance.suite.yml" file. And when I run again your commandline, the url does not change, the url choosen by the test is the url I just defined in the "acceptance.suite.yml" (my codeception version : 2.4)

Comment: Try to configure it leaving blank ulr and browser in default... idk why that code is not working for you but probably your problem is that your WebDriver has default values, i edit my answer edit to match what i mean.

Comment: it's progressing (no error now), but the url is overrided by the value "data:". See my initial post, I add an EDIT part with screenshoots

Comment: that's why i say that the Default should be `WebDriver: {}`... idk why it doesn't work for you :( The last try you can do is give some value to the chrome env and leave a clean WebDriver in default module (edit answer).